# Trigger an event on primeng multiselect dialog close

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to use primeng multiselect component. I want to get all the selected values as soon as the user dismisses the multiselect dropdown. Is there a way to do it? I know we have onChange() event but it triggers every time user selects or deselects a value from the list. I want to trigger it when the user is done selecting the values.

Comment: onPanelHide() is what you really need, I tracked the method's existence to as far back as [version 7](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v7-lts/#/multiselect) up until the current [version 17](https://primeng.org/multiselect#api.multiselect.emitters.onPanelHide) and it doesn't look like it's going away anytime soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As primeng does not provide any api to achieve what you need directly, here is one way i am able to do it.

your.component.html

```
<p-multiSelect #ms [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars"></p-multiSelect>
```

your.component.ts

```
import { Renderer} from '@angular/core';
import {MultiSelect} from 'primeng/primeng';

@ViewChild('ms') multiselect: MultiSelect;

constructor(private renderer  :Renderer) {}

ngOnInit(){
     this.renderer.listenGlobal('document', 'click', ()=> {
        if (!this.multiselect.selfClick && !this.multiselect.panelClick && this.multiselect.overlayVisible) {
          console.log('multiselect will hide'); // write code here to execute when multiselect overlay get dismissed/hidden
          // this.selectedCars will have all the selected values.
        }
    });
}
```

Primeng use same logic to dismiss multiselect overlay when user click anywhere other than multiselect itself.
If in the future primeng provide direct way of achieving the desired result , you may not need to use this work around.

Comment: exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I already made this as a comment but to help anyone who comes straight to the answers:
Primeng provides an `onPanelHide()` method to help respond to the dismissal of the p-multiselect dropdown panel.

I also went ahead to confirm that this method exists across all of it's documented versions [v7](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v7-lts/#/multiselect) to the latest [v17](https://primeng.org/multiselect#api.multiselect.emitters.onPanelHide).

##### Example usage

In your .component.html template:

```
        <p-multiSelect
          [options]="tableColumns"
          [(ngModel)]="selectedColumns"
          placeholder="Choose Columns"
          (onPanelHide)="onTableConfigPanelHide()"
        ></p-multiSelect>
```

In the corresponding .component.ts file

```
  onTableConfigPanelHide() {
    // Do whatever
  }
```